# Can I make jest fail on missing snapshots?

Tags: jestjs, snapshot-testing

I would like to ensure, that I always commit my snapshot files and none are missing in my repository.

Currently when I do not commit a snapshot file, my build on the CI does not fail because it only fails on a mismatch, and would just generate the file, if it does not exist.

Is there any way I can make my build fail when a snapshot file is not found?

I did not find anything on https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing

Comment: Could not reproduce, when I run tests with a missing snapshot and the standard `CI=true` env var, I got _"New snapshot was not written. The update flag must be explicitly passed to write a new snapshot. This is likely because this test is run in a continuous integration (CI) environment in which snapshots are not written by default."_

Comment: Thanks we were missing the ci option (https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--ci) don't know how we could have missed it!